# Could find the requirement text file in Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am performing the Azure Devops pipeline task but I am getting the error path or dir no found.But when I try to run the command `pip install -r requirements.txt` in the project directory, I get this error:

```
trigger: none
resources:
    webhooks:
    - webhook: testspa_new          ### Webhook alias
      connection: testspa_new
      filters:
        - path: pull_request.merged  
          value: true
        - path: pull_request.base.ref  
          value: "develop"
 repositories:
    - repository: Mytest  
      type: githubenterprise
      name: karu/Mytest
      ref: develop
      endpoint: myrepo1
stages:
 - stage: UnlockedPackage_Creation
   jobs:
      - job: Build 
        timeoutInMinutes: 360
        pool:
         vmImage: ubuntu-latest
         
        steps:
        
        - checkout: self
          path: scripts-deploy
        - checkout: Mytest
        
        - task: UsePythonVersion@0
        - script: |
            python -m pip install --upgrade pip
            pip install -r requirements.txt   
        #- script: pip install -r requirements.txt
        #  displayName: 'Install requirements'
        - bash: 
           pip install wheel --upgrade
           pip install dohq-artifactory
           pip install hvac
```

Error:

> ERROR: Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'requirements.txt'
> ##[debug]Exit code 1 received from tool '/usr/bin/bash'
> ##[debug]STDIO streams have closed for tool '/usr/bin/bash'
> ##[error]Bash exited with code '1'

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8g6zT.png)

I tried through cmd line task in python script

Comment: you are in the wrong path, so either specify a working directory, cd to the folder or specify full path to requirements.txt

Comment: Where exactly does your `requirements.txt` file live? Is it part of the repository? If yes, is it in the root directory?

Answer (score 0):

You are checking out your repository (which contains your requirements.txt I assume) to the directory 'scripts-deploy'. By default you are working in the $(Pipeline.Workspace) directory, as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/steps-checkout?view=azure-pipelines) in the documentation:

> path: string # Where to put the repository. The root directory is $(Pipeline.Workspace).

So to use your requirements.txt you should either add the full relative path or change directory to your 'scripts-deploy' folder. For troubleshooting purposes you might want to add a few commands to check the variables:

```bash
echo 'Print all variables'
printenv | sort
echo 'Print working directory'
pwd
```

This will give you all the output you need to figure out where your requirements.txt file is.

Comment: the issue has been resolved due to unable to read the requirement txt file from root working folder.Thanks